# fontspec warning about fonts when using xelatex as compiler

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsetup

I use the following in my preamble: `\usepackage[times]{fontsetup}`. Document is compiled with xelatex. Everything goes well, but I'm worried about warnings:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "FreeSerifbItalic" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Math".


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'FreeSerifbItalic' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'FreeSerifbItalic' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

...

Package fontspec Warning: Font "FreeSerifbBoldItalic" does not contain
(fontspec)                requested Script "Math".


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'FreeSerifbBoldItalic' with
(fontspec)                script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'FreeSerifbBoldItalic' with
(fontspec)                script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
```

Something of a concern? How can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: But the fontsetup package claims that it easily selects matching math fonts automatically. Should I better contact the developer of the package?

Answer (score 1):

When the `times` option is passed to `fontsetup`, the subpackage `fsptimesot` is loaded, which does (reformatted for readability)

```
\setmainfont{FreeSerifb.otf}[
  ItalicFont=FreeSerifbItalic.otf,
  BoldFont=FreeSerifbBold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=FreeSerifbBoldItalic.otf,
  SmallCapsFont=FreeSerifb-SmallCapsAlt.otf
]

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{FreeSerifb.otf}[
  range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}
]
\setmathfont{FreeSerifbBold.otf}[
  range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}
]
\setmathfont{FreeSerifbBoldItalic.otf}[
  range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}
]
\setmathfont{FreeSerifbItalic.otf}[
  range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}
]
```

Since the `FreeSerifb*` fonts don't have a MATH table, you get those warnings. Nothing to be really worried about. Possibly this can change in the future (those fonts are produced by the same author as `fontsetup`).